# FactorialPower and Factorial

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions

After some computation, I have obtained a function `FactorialPower[1, n, -1]`.
Clearly, `FactorialPower[1, n, -1]` equals `Factorial[n]` for all integer values of `n`. Is there a way to get this clearer representation?

Surprisingly, `FullSimplify[FactorialPower[1, n, -1]]` returns `ComplexInfinity` while `FullSimplify[Factorial[n]]` returns `n!`.

The aforementioned function is one of the solutions of a recursive equation and it would be nice if I could print out just `n!` instead of `FactorialPower[1, n, -1]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are interested in integer `n`, give that information to `FullSimplify`.

```
FullSimplify[FactorialPower[1, n, -1], Assumptions -> {n ∈ Integers, n >= 1}]
```

This reduces to n! as you expect. The problem arises because `FactorialPower` accepts other than integer input.

Comment: Why is the assumption `n >= 1` better than the assumption `n >= 0`? A call `FactorialPower[1, 0, -1]` yields `1`, which equals `0!`. On the other hand, calling `FullSimplify[FactorialPower[1, n, -1], Assumptions -> {n ∈ Integers, n >= 0}]`, I get `ComplexInfinity`.